# Audio Issues with Steam Version of Bully

Tags: bully

I've recently gifted my friend a copy of the game Bully when I picked it up cheap during the Steam Summer Sale 2015, as I played the game on Wii way back when that came out, and absolutely loved it.

He has an unexpected problem though. All of the NPCs in the area are constantly saying their lines, instead of once in a while, and only the ones near him. It is significantly worse than it was in the console version, which could get a little annoying at times, but easily manageable. With the amount of chaos happening, I would not expect him to be able to play anymore.

Does anybody know of a way to fix this? Changing audio settings seems to do absolutely nothing, and the only thing I really saw online is to set the sound to surround sound, which hasn't done anything.

He's not sure of what audio drivers he is using, and he only has a Logitech G930 available right now for audio output.